# Chart js: I'm getting the labels crossed on my pieChart and doughnut. Not able to get the chart itself

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-component

I'm trying to achieve charts with vue js. I'm getting the chart with no chart itself but labels crossed. I've no idea what is going wrong.

[image]

This is supposed to be my pie chart. As you can see I'm getting the labels crossed that means remove all the labelled data and hence gives me an empty chart. Here is my code.

```
export const productChartData = {

  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['Purchased', 'Return', 'Cancelled', 'Shipped', 'Returned'],
    datasets:[
      {
        data: ['22, 33, 12, 18, 19'],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options:{
    maintainAspectRatio:false,
    title:{
      display:true,
      fontSize:18,
      text: "Products"
    }
  }

}

export default productChartData;
```

On my .vue file,

```
methods: {
      createChart(chartId, chartData){
        const canvas = document.getElementById(chartId);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: chartData.type,
          data: chartData.data,
          options: chartData.options
        });
      }   
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide a live example of your problem?
Like this: https://codepen.io/dinsmore/pen/pyGJMd

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqKVbm can you produce this pie?Cant make it working there @DavidRaluy

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in your chart rendering code:

`data: ['22, 33, 12, 18, 19']` should be passed as `data: [22, 33, 12, 18, 19]`. I have modified the pen and it's working -> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwKjqM

Comment: Yup, no issue for me on Firefox. rey-young, Is this codepen working for ou?